# finding the area created by a curve

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> find the area created inside $y^2=x^4(4+x)$

because it is not a 1-1 function it should be separated to $y=x^2\sqrt{4+x}$ and $y=-x^2\sqrt{4+x}$

finding the limits of integration $0=x^2\sqrt{4+x}$ shows the limits are from $-4$ to $0$.

$$\int_{-4}^{0}x^2\sqrt{4+x}--x^2\sqrt{4+x}dx=2\int_{-4}^{0}x^2\sqrt{4+x}dx$$

$u=4+x\Rightarrow x^2=(u-4)^2$

$du=dx$

$$2\int_{0}^{4}(u-4)^2\sqrt{u}  du$$

$v=\sqrt{u}$

$dv=\frac{du}{2\sqrt{u}}\Rightarrow du=2\sqrt{u}dv$

$$\int_{0}^{2}(v^2-4)^{2}dv=\int_{0}^{2}v^4-8v^2+16=\frac{v^5}{5}-\frac{8v^3}{3}+16v$$

$$\frac{(2)^5}{5}+\frac{8(2)^3}{3}+16*2=17.06$$

Now it is positive but the [answer is 39](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=area%20inside%20y%5E2%3Dx%5E4(4%2Bx))

Comment: $d\nu = \frac{du}{2\sqrt{u}}$ without minus.

Comment: @echzhen  thanks edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in the following line

$$2\int\limits_0^4(u-4)^2\sqrt u du = \int\limits_0^2(\nu^2-4)^2d\nu$$
meanwhile, assuming that $\nu = \sqrt u \implies d\nu = \frac{du}{2 \sqrt u} \implies du = 2\nu d\nu$
$$2\int\limits_0^4(u-4)^2\sqrt u du = 4\int\limits_0^2(\nu^2-4)^2\nu^2 d\nu $$

Comment: but if $dv=\frac{du}{2\sqrt{u}}$ cant I multiple both side to get $dv*2\sqrt{u}=du$?

Comment: that is exactly what I did. Just notice that $2\sqrt{u} = 2\nu$

Comment: What I did is $2\int\limits_0^4(u-4)^2\sqrt u du=\int\limits_0^4 2(u-4)^2\sqrt u du=\int\limits_0^4(v-4)^2 dv$ why is wrong?

Comment: The problem is that $2\sqrt{u}du \neq d\nu$, but $2\nu d\nu = du$

Comment: ok the coin finally fall, thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome, good luck :)